# Question about a degree 5 polynomial with no rational roots

Tags: functions, polynomials

Is it possible to find a 5th degree polynomial with no rational roots, and at least one irrational root?

Edit: the polynomial must only have rational coefficients

Comment: how about $(x-\pi)^5$ or $(x-e)^5$ or $(x-\sqrt2)^5$?

Comment: Or even just $x^5-2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact we can even achieve this with a polynomial with rational coefficients: [*Edit*: After I wrote this answer, OP added the rationality of the coefficients as a condition.]

The [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) implies that $$x^5 - 2$$ has no rational roots, but since its degree is odd, it has at least one real---and hence irrational---root. (In fact, can replace $2$ here with any rational number that is not a perfect $5$th power of a rational number.)

Comment: in fact with integer coefficients

Comment: Indeed! That said, we can always clear the denominators of any rational polynomial by multiplying by their $\operatorname{lcm}$, and this operation preserves the roots. (But it's true that this example is a monic polynomial with integer coefficients.)

Answer (score 2):

$$ x^5 + x^4 - 4  x^3 - 3  x^2 + 3  x + 1 $$

Five real irrational roots, 
$$ 2 \cos \left( \frac{2k 
\pi}{11} \right)  $$

[image]

If you prefer the roots to be $\cos( 2k \pi /11),$ adjust the quintic to

$$ 32x^5 + 16x^4 - 32  x^3 - 12  x^2 + 6  x + 1 $$

[image]

gp-pari:

```
? x = cos( 2 * Pi / 11)
%1 = 0.8412535328311811688618116489
? f = 32 * x^5 + 16 * x^4 - 32 * x^3 - 12 * x^2 + 6 * x + 1
%2 = -1.009741959 E-28
? 
? x = cos( 4 * Pi / 11)
%3 = 0.4154150130018864255292741493
? f = 32 * x^5 + 16 * x^4 - 32 * x^3 - 12 * x^2 + 6 * x + 1
%4 = -2.019483917 E-28
? 
? x = cos( 6 * Pi / 11)
%5 = -0.1423148382732851404437926686
? f = 32 * x^5 + 16 * x^4 - 32 * x^3 - 12 * x^2 + 6 * x + 1
%6 = -7.57306469 E-29
? 
? x = cos( 8 * Pi / 11)
%7 = -0.6548607339452850640569250725
? f = 32 * x^5 + 16 * x^4 - 32 * x^3 - 12 * x^2 + 6 * x + 1
%8 = 0.E-28
?
```

=============================

Comment: I'm confused, how did you connect polynomials to triginometry? Through something like taylor series?

Comment: @vikarjramun goes back to Gauss, modern treatment in http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/cox_galois_Gaussian_periods.pdf  and many, many examples in https://books.google.com/books?id=wt7lgfeYqMQC&pg=PR1&lpg=PR1&dq=reuschle++tafeln+complexer+primzahlen&source=bl&ots=VGZFPrfUBn&sig=MlQ667PqXaQ9rAvLWkG3_F1rwsk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIwtSvm9TQAhUJ-2MKHXJIA_kQ6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false

Answer (score 2):

Well,  $\sqrt[5]{m}$ is irrational if $m$ is an integer that isn't a perfect power of $5$.

And $\sqrt[5]{m}$ is a solution to $x^5 -m =0$.

And as $x^5 -m =0\implies x^5 = m\implies x =\sqrt [5]{m}$ so that is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty easy, if there are not other propertys required. Just consider a polynomial like:

$(x-\sqrt{2})^5$

Comment: That doesn't have rational coefficients.

Comment: @fleablood OP added the requirement that the coefficients be rational a few minutes after this answer was posted.

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha$ is irrational, then the polynomial $(x-\alpha)^5$ has degree $5$, and the only (repeated) root is irrational.

Comment: More generally, $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)(x-a_4)(x-a_5)$ for any irrational $a_1, \dots, a_5$.

Comment: I realize now that I might have phrased the question badly- it is only considering polynomials with rational coefficients.

Comment: @DibaHeydary:  In that case, see the answer by [Travis](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/155629/travis)